# How to change the Fallback Characters in

Tags: c#, .net

I want to create a text file in plain ASCII from a string. So i use File.WriteAllText with the encoding Encoding.ASCII:

```
File.WriteAllText(_param.pathFileOut + "\\" + _param.batch_id + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".txt", _fileOut, Encoding.ASCII);
```

When a non ASCII character is encountered, he is converted to '?'. How can i specify to Encoding.ASCII or to File.WriteAllText to use another characters than '?' as a fallback character?

Comment: Or you could throw an exception so users know you are discarding their data. Consider if that would apply in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a different encoding object that matches what you need. For example to use the string `"[NON-ASCII]"` for replacements for both encoding and decoding, you could use:

```
var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(
  "US-Ascii",
  new EncoderReplacementFallback("[NON-ASCII]"),
  new DecoderReplacementFallback("[NON-ASCII]"));

File.WriteAllText(
  _param.pathFileOut + "\\" + _param.batch_id + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".txt",
  _fileOut,
  encoding);
```

As should be obvious, we can't use a character in `EncoderReplacementFallback` that can't be encoded with the encoding in question. If we try this it's accepted but will throw if a replacement is ever needed. We can use such characters for the decoder though:

```
var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(
    "US-Ascii",
    new EncoderReplacementFallback("�"),
    new DecoderReplacementFallback("�"));
Console.WriteLine(encoding.GetString(new byte[]{234})); // Prints �
var bytes = encoding.GetBytes("þ"); // Throws Argument Exception:
                                    // Recursive fallback not allowed for character \uFFFD.
                                    // Parameter name: chars
```